# What does the game of "Pong" look like in Binary?

Tags: binary, pong

I'm trying to learn "concepts," and from what I understand in programming, everything we do with coding in the various languages is in order to compile the language into something that a computer can interpret.  From this, I think I've read (correct me if I'm wrong) that computers basically work in binary (yes or no, open or closed circuit, go or stop).

From this understanding, basically everything can be translated into binary I'm guessing?

What does a simple game like pong look like in binary?  I couldn't find it on Bing or anything...  Perhaps this may not be relevant, and this isn't something I'll ever need to know, but it's just out of curiosity, and I have no idea where else to ask this.

Or if no one actually has the binary code... What would it look like?  Would you be able to differentiate (with experience of course) which aspects of the binary is related to graphics, and which are related to movement, and which are related to boundaries?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  You need to learn about machine language and assembler, and about higher-level concepts like video cards.

Comment: If you want to "see" what a program looks like, open your favorite executable in a hex editor.

Comment: Hex editor, that's the answer I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you've got Pong binary for machine XYZ: without a solid understanding about how the CPU and peripherals like video output work on that machine, it's just going to be a bunch of bits. Almost nobody works with that. At the very least, one would disassemble the binary and get an assembler program.

So without a *lot* of knowledge about how computers work (and especially the particular machine on which a particular Pong binary would run), it's absolutely useless to look at the binary.